# How to loop through array to find all occurrences of an element C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, console-application

I'm pretty new to programming,

I have two arrays that correspond with eachother.
The First displays student names the other displays the students grade.

My goal is to loop through the arrays and print out all of the students who have the grade
87 for example.

As of right now I am able to print the first person with that grade, however the loop ends once it finds the first grade.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to find ALL of the people with that grade. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
     public static void OptionTwo()
    {
        LoadArray();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a student grade to see all students with that grade");
        int userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int subscript;

        subscript = Search(studentGrade, userInput, ref counter);
        ShowResults(userInput, subscript, counter);
    }

    public static int Search(int[] studentGrade, int userInput, ref int counter)
    {
        counter = 0;

        for (int s = 0; s < studentGrade.Length; s++)
        {
            counter++;                             

            if (studentGrade[s] == userInput)
                return s;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void ShowResults(int userInput, int subscript, int counter)
    {

        //LOOP THROUGH ARRAY
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("The following students have that grade: ");
        Console.WriteLine();

            if (subscript == -1)
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is NOT in array, # of comparisons is {1}",
                    userInput, counter);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", studentName[subscript].PadRight(20), studentGrade[subscript].ToString().PadRight(5));
    }
```

Comment: It stops because you return immediately after finding the first match. You should continue and save all the indexes found in another array (or better a `List<int>`)  and then return that array or list.

Comment: You return immediately when you find one result. Rather change the code to add the results to a list and then result an array based on that. Then give that to the output method. Also it's not smart to have separate arrays for this, better learn basic object oriented methods and create a class that includes the data. This way you don't get mismatching arrays ever.

Comment: Parallel arrays of "associated" data is usually not a good idea. A better way to "associate" the data is by putting them into a `class Student { }`, then you just have an array of the `class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's state the problem. We have two arrays:

```
 string[] studentName = new string[] {
   "Amy", "Bob", "Charly", "Dimitry", "Eva",
 };

 int[] studentGrade = new int[] {
   80, 70, 80, 95, 68,         
 };
```

And you want to get all the students with the given grade. E.g. `"Amy"` and `"Charly"` for `80`.
If it's your case you have to scan both arrays:

```
 private static List<string> Search(string[] studentName, int[] studentGrade, int grade) {
   List<string> result = new List<string>();

   // Let's use good old for loop instead of Linq
   for (int i = 0; i < studentGrade.Length; ++i)
     if (studentGrade[i] == grade)
       result.Add(studentName[i]);

   return result; 
 }

 public static void ShowResults(int userInput) {
   Console.WriteLine();
   Console.WriteLine("The following students have that grade: ");
   Console.WriteLine();

   List<string> list = Search(studentGrade, studentName, userInput); 

   if (list.Count <= 0)
     Console.WriteLine("{0} is NOT in array", userInput);
   else
     Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", string.Join(", ", list), userInput);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Dmitry.

Answer (score 1):

Good programming is the art of reducing cognitive load. In your architecture, you - the programmer - know that both arrays are related to each other. If you create a Student class as such:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name;
    public int Grade;
}
```

Now you can create a

```
var students = new List<Student>();
```

At this point, the compiler knows to associate student names and their grades, and you don't have to remember which arrays are correlated.

You can now return your filtered list using System.Linq as such:

```
return students.Where(x => x.Grade == 87);
```

You have reduced cognitive load. This may seem trivial for your example, but it becomes central to good programming in a large organization where you will spend most of your time maintaining someone else's code.

Answer (score 0):

Linq is perfect for it:

```
  var choosenGrades = studentGrade.Where(x=>x == userInput).ToList();
```

Remember to add import `System.Linq`

Answer (score 0):

The reason your loop is ending after one is because you are returning the first instance of the subscript and the function ends there.

you should create a list of subscripts to return.

so you search function should be changed to something like this

```
public static List<int> Search(int[] studentGrade, int userInput, ref int counter)
    {
        var listOfSubscripts = new List<int>();
        counter = 0;

        for (int s = 0; s < studentGrade.Length; s++)
        {
            counter++;                             

            if (studentGrade[s] == userInput)
                listOfSubscripts.Add(s);
        }

        return listOfSubscripts;
    }
```

And then your show results function should be like

```
public static void ShowResults(int userInput, List<int> subscripts, int counter)
{

    //LOOP THROUGH ARRAY
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("The following students have that grade: ");
    Console.WriteLine();

        if (subscript == -1)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is NOT in array, # of comparisons is {1}",
                userInput, counter);
        else
        {
            foreach(var subscript in subscripts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", studentName[subscript].PadRight(20), studentGrade[subscript].ToString().PadRight(5));
            }
        }
}
```